# How can I return the number of certain items in a String Array list?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

So I'm trying to make a simple program that has an array which models a college class. You can add students to the class (called IOOP), get their first and last name, standing, quiz scores, quiz averages, final exam averages, etc. The array takes students as its items, and one of the methods is called printFinalExamDetails. My professor wants us to not only display the average final exam score of the entire class (which I already coded), but to also display the avg final exam score for freshman, sophomore, juniors, and seniors. My code looks like this right now:

```
public void printFinalExamDetails ( ) { 
    double sum, counter; sum = 0;
    for (Student x : students ) 
    {
        sum = sum + x.getFinalExamScore();
        counter = students.size();
        System.out.println (x.getFirstName()  +  " " + x.getLastName( ) + ": " + x.getFinalExamScore( ) );
        System.out.println ("The average final exam score is: " + sum/counter + ".");


        String standing = x.computeStanding();
        if(standing.equals("freshman"))
        System.out.println ("The average final exam score for the freshmen is: " + sum/counter + ".");


        if(standing.equals("sophomore"))
        System.out.println("The average final exam score for the sophomore is: " + sum/counter + ".");

      }
}
```

Now I'm afraid using counter again and again will use the full size of the class and not just the freshman/sophs/juniors/seniors, and if I use students.size(), it will print ALL the students in the array, not just the freshmen. Can anyone give me some hints as to how to code this? Thanks!

Comment: Please, _properly_ format your code.

Comment: What is the purpose of `counter`? Is it just a number for class size? Why not just call it classSize?

Comment: You need to understand that average score for the class is `sum of score for all students/total no. of students`. Average score for sophomores is `sum of score for all sophomores/total no. of sophomores`. Average score for freshers is `sum of score for all freshers/total no. of freshers`. Try updating you code based on this.

Comment: This code is not going to have the intended effect. What is printed when the first student goes through your for loop? And the second? And the rest? For that matter, do you want to be printing something every time a student goes through?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the problem is that you have one variable representing the number of students in the class (`counter`, which could use a better name) and you're concerned that because it's a sum of the whole class, you won't be able to accurately average the scores for only students with certain standings.

Well, then the solution is either to iterate through your list of students and have individual counts for how many Freshmen, Sophomores, etc. you have or change to a better data structure that makes it easier to determine the size of each class.

Since this is a homework problem, I won't give you the code, but the former can be done with a simple `for` loop. Just loop through all students and count up how many of them are in each class. You can sum up their scores while you're at it.

Perhaps the most efficient way to use it is to change the data structure of Students to be a HashMap. You could set your keys to be a String of the class standing of the student and then values to be an ArrayList of each students in that class. This way, you can more easily get just the students of the class you want and be able to determine the number of students per class via `map.values().getSize()`.

Comment: I seem to have got it. My code can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/YNSLQH4u

I tested it and it works! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Glad you got it! Please choose this as the accepted answer by clicking on the checkbox underneath the value of this answer.